# PHP Global PDO object in constructor

Tags: php, pdo, constructor

I have an "Email" class. What I am attempting to do is connecting database with PDO. But I want PDO object being accessable from any function of the class I defined. Therefore I tried to build a constructor logic. What I did to achieve this is:

```
Class Email
{
protected $dbh;

public function __construct()
{
    if (isset($_GET['rm']) && method_exists('Email', $_GET['rm'])) {
        $this->$_GET['rm']();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No such a function";
    }

    $this->dbh = $this->connect_db();
}

public function index()
{
    var_dump($this->dbh);
}

private function connect_db()
{
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=email", $username, $password);
        return $dbh;
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
$email = new Email();
```

When I var_dump PDO object in index method it comes as "null".

Why does not it work you guys think? And how can I improve this structure?
Thank you!

Comment: Executing a function based directly on untrusted input ($_GET) is incredibly insecure, and doing it automatically in the constructor means you can never reuse that code in any other context.

Comment: I am working on localhost. This is just for managing to access this->Class via my browser.

Comment: how do you receive $_GET parameters from a constructor, I am not sure how is your code working

Comment: @meza , You are right .. I actually did this `localhost/test.php?rm=index`  for this code to work ;)

Comment: Ok. It's still a good idea to get into good coding practices though - for instance, if this is just for debugging, you could build the $_GET handling into a separate test file, and keep the "real" code clean. If it's permanent, there's no reason not to build a proper code structure.

Comment: In fact, if you'd kept your test code separate from the constructor, you wouldn't have had this problem.

Comment: It is working like a charm! So, Could you please explain why do/dont I recieve $_GET parameters from a constructor? @IMSoP

Comment: at least you should do that from the controller, then pass the method to the constructor maybe?:

    `if (isset($_GET['rm'])) {
       $method = $_GET['rm'];
    $email = new Email($method);
    }`

Comment: The constructor's job is to get the object ready for use, not to perform any actual actions. Your test code should first create an object, and then exercise one or more methods of that object. Your tests can then be arbitrarily complex, and are closer to "real" use of the object. You can also separate the decision of which test to run from the implementation of the tests, so you could for instance run multiple tests on one page.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran It is too interesting that you start to make a study of my question AFTER I accepted Markus's answer. If you see something wrong PLEASE edit it after the question is asked I mean please say it right away!

Comment: It seems that ShankarDamodaran only edited for the purpose of editing. Nothing substantial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does not it work you guys think?

Probably because you are calling a method on an uninitialized object:

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (isset($_GET['rm']) && method_exists('Email', $_GET['rm'])) {
        $this->$_GET['rm']();  // <- call on an uninitialized object
    }
    // […]
    $this->dbh = $this->connect_db(); // <- too late initialization
}
```

This constructor calls a method (`$this->$_GET['rm']()`) which relies on a properly initialized object. But the property `$dbh` will be initialized after that method call.

Instead of fixing that (by moving initialization of `$dbh` before that call) you should throw that piece of code away! It's a very dangerous idea to call whatever method a request wants (`$_GET['rm']`). Furthermore it's an odd idea to have side effects in a constructor. Let the constructor initialize your object only and call the method on that initialized object.

> And how can I improve this structure?

You're looking for Dependency Injection. One very simple approach could be a constructor based DI:

```
public function __construct(PDO $dbh)
{
    $this->dbh = $dbh;
}
```

Besides that there are some [DI container for PHP](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+dependency+injection). Choose one of your favour (e.g. [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/)) or the one which comes with the choice of your framework.

Comment: could you explain your answer? maybe give an example of how you would apply dependency injection, and of how to initialize the `object` you claim is not, while quoting lines defining a `property`?

Comment: I did not downvote. $_GET['rm'](); is temprory solution to access my class via browser. I am working on localhost.

Comment: It is appreciated. I have misunderstood the part where `$this->$_GET['rm']();` actually evaluated as `$this->Email()`

Answer (score -1):

You need to move this

```
 $this->dbh = $this->connect_db();
```

into the `if` statement.

#### Like this..

```
public function __construct()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['rm']) && method_exists('Email', $_GET['rm'])) {
            $this->dbh = $this->connect_db(); //<----- Moved here !
            $this->$_GET['rm']();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No such a function";
        }

    }
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
object(PDO)[2]
```

#### Reason for your `NULL`:

You are getting `NULL` because , you are trying to `var_dump()` the object , even before it was assigned the value from the `connect_db()`

Comment: While this answers one of OP's questions the IMO more important question "how can I improve this structure?" is unanswered. Furthermore your answer propagates two flaws in the design.